# Why is my for loop not iterating over every element? it just stops after the first?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to get an input from user and checking if their input is in a list. If it is, I want to replace a blank list with the corresponding answer. i.e:

```py
base = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
blank = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

if the guess was 2 it would look like:

```py
base = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
blank = [0,2,0,0,2,0]
```

Here is my code:

```
base = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
x = len(base)
blank = ['0'] * x

g = int(input('Input a number: '))

for i in base:
    ind = base.index(i)
    if i is g:
        blank[ind] = base[ind]

print(base, '\n', blank)
```

Comment: It does not stop after the first, but the `base.index(2)` always returns 1.

Comment: Don't use `is` when you really mean `==`.

Comment: Providing a sample of the current "incorrect" output that your code gives will be helpful. You say it's not working —what is it doing instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.index()` is only giving you the first index of the item in the list. (I'm talking about line `ind = base.index(i)` in your loop)

Instead you can find all the indexes with a list comprehension, then iterate over it and assign `g` to them:

```py
base = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
blank = ["0"] * len(base)

g = int(input("Input a number: "))

indexes = [i for i, item in enumerate(base) if item == g]
for i in indexes:
    blank[i] = g

print(base)
print(blank)
```

output:

```
Input a number: 2
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
['0', 2, '0', '0', 2, '0']
```

But, there is also another solution for this, you don't need to first create your `blank` list. Do it in one shot:

```py
base = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

g = int(input("Input a number: "))

blank = [g if item == g else "0" for item in base]

print(base)
print(blank)
```

**Note:** Do not use `is` for comparing `int` objects. use `==`.

Comment: You are a god among men, thank you! Also, if you dont mind, could you explain what exactly the: indexes = [i for i, item in enumerate(base) if item == g], line is doing? I want to understand it rather than the ol ctrl c v

Comment: @BadBoyBean You're welcome. It's called list-comprehension. Take a look at [this article](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/) for more details. Basically we're creating a list of indexes but we filter them to include those items which are equal to `g`. The right side of the list comprehension is called the "filter part". The left side is called the "expression part", it's what gets stored in the list.